# Check number ID with Preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

i've a little problem.

I want to check the numer of post like this:

http://xxx.xxxxxx.net/episodio/168

this is part of my code, only need the number check:

```
[...]
if(preg_match('#^http://horadeaventura.enlatino.net/episodio/[0-9]',trim($url))){
[...]
```

Can help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it with preg_match:

```
$url = 'http://horadeaventura.enlatino.net/episodio/168';
if(preg_match('#^http://horadeaventura.enlatino.net/episodio/([0-9]+)#',trim($url), $matches)){
    $post = $matches[1];
    echo $post;
}
```

So, basically: I added an end delimiter (#), changed "[0-9]" to "([0-9])+", added ", $matches" to capture the matches. Of course it can be done better and using other options than preg_match. But I wanted to make your snippet work - not rewrite it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have your heart set on using preg_match(), you could do

```
$string = "http://xxx.xxxxxx.net/episodio/168";

$array = explode("/", $string);

echo end($array);
```

which will output

```
168
```

*this is assuming the number you are looking for will always be the last section of the url string*

Comment: Maybe work, but how adapt this to the rest of code? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9762635cf3d01e3367b2

Comment: Well, I just wanted to give an answer that would make Ferrrmolina's code snippet work. But I also suggested there are better ways.. When I build an application, usually early in the application I do: `$nodes =  array_values(array_filter(explode("/" , $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])))`, similar to Endacy's answer. I then make sure I can use it anywhere in the application - for example to find an id. In your case the post id would be $nodes[1] if it's a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can just check **for number**, on last position:

```
if(preg_match('#[0-9]+$#',trim($url),$match)){

print_r($match);

}
```